# Keyboard short cut for firebug "Edit watch"

Tags: firefox, firebug

In the firebug plugin for Firefox, under the Script Tab, in the right hand side window, there is the watch tab. Here you can enter a variable name, or javascript expression and have it evaluated.

If you need to change that expression, you can right click it, and select "Edit watch expression..." On occasion you can double click it, and it will let you edit, but sometimes this does not work. Usually when you are watching an object.

Is there a keyboard short cut to edit the selected watch expression? Or a consistent way to use double click to edit, instead of expanding the object.

I expected <kbd>F2</kbd> to work, but that does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that if you double click in the far right of the input section (just to the left of the delete button) then firebug will start editing the watch for you.